# C# .NET Generate success message based on form sections

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have a form with multiple sections, for an example section A, B, C and D. and one submit button to save them. My customer needs me to show different success messages based on the action when user clicks on the Submit button. 
 1) when user changes A and C, success message should be "A and C saved". 
 2) When user changes A, C and D the success message should be "A, C and D saved". 
 And it goes like that. 
 At the moment its lot of if and else conditions. I checked each section, whether it's modified or not by the user, and set a bool variable to true or false. and based on these bool variables I generate the success message. 
 Even though it works fine, I don't like the whole bunch of if and else conditions. So I wanted to have your thoughts. How can I address this issue more elegant way. Let's say in future I add another section, I don't want to go through all these if, else conditions. 
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set up:

```
Dictionary<string,bool> responses = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
```

where keys are "A", "B", "C" etc.
When You check sections, you simply set true/false for each response/key.
Then You can use helper method to join letter with commas and 'and' word:

```
static string MyJoin(Dictionary<string,bool> dict)
        {
            var dictTrue = dict.Where(e=>e.Value);
            if(dictTrue.Count()==0) return string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(string.Join(", ",dictTrue.Select(e=>e.Key).Take(dictTrue.Count()-1)));
            sb.Append(" and ");
            sb.Append(dictTrue.Last().Key);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'll give a go and post here

Comment: This works fine and thanks Robert. But Im still open to suggestions :)